# Mixed ANOVA vs Ordinal logistic mixed model?

Tags: anova, ordered-logit, treatment-effect

I have two different groups, Treatment A vs Treatment B, with measurements for each individual in four different time points. That is a 2 x 4 design. The dependent variable is a discrete scale from 1 to 4 where 1 is better than 4. The fact that it is a discrete scale means that computing means and standard deviations doesn't make sense (it can't be 2.7 for instance).

Thus, the problem I have is to understand if I could use a Mixed-Factorial ANOVA to analyze whether there are differences between groups and across individuals. A colleague has suggested me to use an Ordinal Logistic Mixed Model which seems a legit approach as well. However, given the nature of the data it looks to me that a Mixed-Factorial ANOVA would be perfectly fine (it is a numeric and ordered scale, although the scale has few levels).

Furthermore, it seems that there aren't good implementations of Mixed Ordered Logit in standard software like R or SPSS for instance.

I would really appreciate if you could give me your insights about how to tackle this problem and which model is better.

Comment: Have a look at the `ordinal` package, it has an ANOVA however I don't know how you are going to add random effects.

Comment: Random effects are possible in the ordinal package, do ?clmm after installing and loading it.

Comment: The `ordinal` package in R is relatively easy to use, and has pretty much everything one could ask for.  It does handle mixed-effects designs.  It also allows you to specify if the ordered categories should be assumed to equidistant, symmetrical, or neither.  Group separations can be determined with the `emmeans` package.  One thing to be aware of: (last I checked) absolutely don't use `car::Anova` with models from this package unless you use it with the `RVAideMemoire` package.

Answer (score 2):

If your DV is ordinal, you probably don't want ANOVA as it assumes a continuous DV. It also assumes that the errors are normally distributed, which is unlikely when you have a four level DV.

Jade Schmidt wrote a paper ["Ordinal Response Mixed Models"](http://www.math.montana.edu/jobo/writing/documents/schmidt.pdf) that both discusses this sort of problem and compares various R packages. I didn't read it in extensive detail, but it looked pretty good from a quick skim (but it seems not to be a peer reviewed paper).

Comment: The Schmidt article is worth looking at.  It's pretty approachable, but also mentions a few technical considerations.  It mostly discusses the approach to ordinal regression used by the `ordinal` package in R. [The vignette for this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_article.pdf) is also very informative.

Answer (score 1):

There are good implementations of mixed ordered logistic regression in R, check `clmm()` in the ordinal package. If your model will include additional predictors and some of them are continuous, then try `clmm()`.

If the only predictors will be the cell membership of your factorial design, then a standard linear mixed model will give you relatively similar results to your ordinal mixed model. As an exercise, run both, your p-values will not be too dissimilar. And it will be much easier to interpret the linear mixed model results. Depending on the outlet/audience for your work, you may have flexibility in which you choose to report.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem with `clmm` is that when specifying the Random Effects variable, which is Treatment (treated vs control) shows an error saying that there should be 3 levels or more `Error : all(sapply(gfl, nlevels) > 2) is not TRUE ` how would you overcome such problem? Thanks!

Comment: @adrian1121 the random intercept should be on the individual. A quick review of mixed models might help here.

Comment: With the caveat that this links to my own webpage, [there is a relatively simple and complete example with `ordinal::clmm` here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_08.html).